# Unable to set environment variable in compile time of uBoot

Tags: yocto, u-boot, yocto-recipe

I am trying to bring net-console in uboot. For that, I first added 'ncip' in "uboot-imx/include/configs/imx8mm_evk.h" as following. Later, **DFMC_SWUG** is called at the end of **CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS**.

```
#define DFMC_SWUG \
"setenv ncip 192.168.100.98 \0" \
"ethaddr=00:80:A3:CA:B5:77 \0" \
"swugip=192.168.100.16 \0" \
"ipaddr=192.168.100.2 \0" \
"serverip=192.168.100.16 \0" \
"bootdelay=3\0" \

#define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS       \
CONFIG_MFG_ENV_SETTINGS \
JAILHOUSE_ENV \
"script=boot.scr\0" \
--
    --
    --
    "fi;\0" \
    DFMC_SWUG
```

Interestingly, I was able to set 'ethaddr', "swugip" and other variables except "ncip". I guess, I am doing some formatting mistakes in line --> "setenv ncip 192.168.100.98 \0" \

Later I tried setting some dummy variables named dummy_var_1, dummy_var_2, dummy_var_3. Even they are not getting set.

[image: Trying to set some dummy_variables]

Can some one please guide me here?

Comment: All working values seem to have an equals sign between the name and the value, which ncip does not.

Comment: Hi Joachim, I did try "ncip=192.168.100.98" but that didn't work as well. What understand is (i may be wrong) "ncip" is not yet set by uboot and hence it requires us using "setenv ncip <ipaddr>"

Comment: You probably need a `;` at the end of the setenv line : `"setenv ncip 192.168.100.98; \0" \
`

Comment: tried that too :( Not working!!

Comment: You have to check if a `boot.scr` file exists in your boot partition, because Uboot, in your case, will try to load it first. Or try to add your env variable in the beginning, before `JAILHOUSE_ENV`

Answer (score 0):

The U-Boot environment consists of strings in the form `<env_var>=<string value><null>` (and preceded with a CRC32 word).
So strings for environment variables have to conform to that template when predefining them in code using **CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS**.
That also means that you cannot install raw commands in the environment such as `"setenv ncip 192.168.100.98 \0"`.

---

The U-Boot documentation is clear on this topic.
Note the last sentence of the warning.

```
- Default Environment:
    CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS

    Define this to contain any number of null terminated
    strings (variable = value pairs) that will be part of
    the default environment compiled into the boot image.

    For example, place something like this in your
    board's config file:

    #define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS \
        "myvar1=value1\0" \
        "myvar2=value2\0"

    Warning: This method is based on knowledge about the
    internal format how the environment is stored by the
    U-Boot code. This is NOT an official, exported
    interface! Although it is unlikely that this format
    will change soon, there is no guarantee either.
    You better know what you are doing here.
```

---

> I did try "ncip=192.168.100.98" ...

That looks almost correct, but needs the explicit null terminator.

---

> Interestingly, I was able to set 'ethaddr', "swugip" and other variables except "ncip".
> ...
> Later I tried setting some dummy variables named dummy_var_1, dummy_var_2, dummy_var_3. Even they are not getting set.

You have only provided your vague summations of the actual results.

Did you inspect any **.o** object files to check what text strings were stored?
Did you perform a `strings u-boot.bin | less` on the U-Boot image file to review the *default* environment embedded in the image?

---

---

Note that you could be making an additional mistake.

The environment variables defined in **CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS** will only (initially) exist in the *default* environment of U-Boot.
You have been very parsimonious with details, and neglect to mention your setup.  If there is an existing and valid *stored* environment in the nonvolatile boot medium, then specific procedures need to be performed to suppress the *existing* *stored* environment in order to revert to the *default* environment with the "new" environment variables.

Failure to disable/delete an existing *stored* environment when installing a new/different version of **u-boot.bin** will conceal the new/different *default* environment and all the new/different variables in it.  If U-Boot does *not* issue the message similar to:

```
Loading Environment from xxx... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment
```

then you can be assured that your new/different environment variables are not in the current runtime environment.
IOW you want to see this warning message on (initial) boot.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer along with nxp forum helped me to solve the issue!!

(https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/unable-to-set-environment-variable-in-compile-time-of-uBoot/m-p/1384753/highlight/false#M184250)

Answer (score 0):

If one wishes to compile u-boot with netconsole then following changes have to be done for the file in uboot-imx/include/configs/imx8mm_evk.h

1. Add ‘ncip’ i.e., IP address of the computer/device which holds net console along with other network settings. Please note that every variable in u-boot will be null terminated string.
2. Also add a variable (in following case it is dfmcswug) which will set the standard input, output and error reporting over netconsole. This variable will be called later.

   [image]
3. Include the DFMC_SWUG macro inside CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS macro so that our new settings will be added along with other environmental settings.
4. Add dfmcswug variable in CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND so that it will get executed by tool chain during run time.

   [image]

With the above steps, u-boot should output its console over netconsole.

On the client-side use Or similar.

```
nc -u -l -p 6666 <ip_address_of_uboot_host>
```